Reducing browser width causes Products & OverflowAI menu items stack on top of each other
This is nothing major, but I noticed that when the browser window width is reduced to +/-890px, the two menu items, Products and OverflowAI, are placed above one another.
When hovering over the items, the highlighted area overlaps the existing borders of the Navigation bar.
Please note:
It was only present when I was logged in.
I am using OSX and verified it on Chrome and Safari.
I could not reproduce it when using Firefox.
Is this unintentional, or is there something obvious I am missing?


I can't seem to reproduce this (Firefox on Windows). Do you have any userscript / userstyle / extension enabled?

I am using a Mac; I could not reproduce it on Firefox.

So probably specific to WebKit based browsers then.

The top bar should now behave the same with or without the sidebar menu enabled. Thanks for the report and repro.

What should happen is that the OverflowAI menu item should disappear, like so:

I can reproduce this problem on Chrome on Windows.
However, I had to hide left navigation sidebar from the user settings on the user profile page found under SITE SETTINGS / Preferences.

The problem seems to be with the s-navigation class on the <ol> element, which you can locate by using Inspect from Chrome's context menu.

If you disable flex-wrap for this tag from Chrome's Styles tab in developer tools, then the problem disappears:

And the layout appears correctly:

I am sure the developers will be able to track down what the exact problem is, although, as you say, it is fairly minor.
I can reproduce this on Chrome (130.0.6723.59), Firefox (131.0.3), and Edge (130.0.2849.46).

Great, now they'll remove that profile option

@KevinB It would probably be easier to just remove the OverflowAI menu option in the top bar. It may well be connected to the hamburger menu too, as that appears on desktop when the left navigation is hidden.

for reference: i was referring to this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368973/we-ve-removed-the-option-to-disable-the-fixed-top-bar TLDR, they kept forgetting to test for various profile options and decided to just remove them because "almost noone was using [this feature we hid away in the profile settings] anyway"
