Please hide the Products menu option on the mobile top navigation bar
There are two menu options on the top navigation which I never use at all:

Products
OverflowAI

On my desktop, it looks like this:

And on my mobile phone, the OverflowAI option disappears and it look like this:

Notice that the current community menu in the top right of the screen is neither visible nor accessible.
To access the community menu (something that I do regularly when on my mobile), I have to touch the inbox icon or the achievements icon (more or less) and drag leftwards (sometimes ending up either in the inbox or the achievements menu), not where I wanted to go. Notice that a horizontal scroll bar appears.
Once the community menu icon appears, I can tap it and go where I want to go.

While investigating Minor styling issue - Reducing browser width causes Products & OverflowAI menu Item styling issue, I noticed (using Chrome's Inspect tool) that only one of the <li> elements had the md:d-none class applied which seems to be responsible for hiding the OverflowAI menu option.

Adding the md:d-none class manually to the Products menu option element <li> as below:

resulted in the Products menu option element disappearing and the Community Menu option reappearing at the top right of the top navigation bar:

Note: changes to the HTML were tested on a desktop with Chrome developer tools
Since it appears to be a trivial fix to hide the Products menu option on mobile, can you please implement this so that we can all access the community menu option easily, or at least please look at ways of replacing the Products menu option with an icon that takes up less space on mobile.
This post is related but that was a discussion and not a feature request.
This post is asking for an option to hide the menu, whereas I am asking for the menu to be hidden automatically on mobile (or narrow screens).

Or just some profile config option, to turn them off no matter what you're browsing on? If you know you're not going to use it, it's just clutter. (I mean, who keeps clean space on their workdesk reserved for the logo of its manufacture and their product catalogue). | Guess that's what one of the linked posts asks for. But I'd love not seeing it on desktop either, without having to constantly mess around with user scripts and adblock settings.

Not about mobile, but these items are causing all kinds of problems: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/431963/minor-styling-issue-reducing-browser-width-causes-products-overflowai-menu-i

@DanMašek Yes, that would also work, but I was reluctant to ask for that because that feature was removed a few years ago as announced here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368973/1242908 Maybe we should be asking for a zen mode.
